# How to capture stacktrace from another point in code, as an inner exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-trace

I have this C# fragment:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var ty = new Thready();
            ty.Culprit();
            ty.Scapegoat();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }
}

public class Thready
{
    string state;
    Exception moreInfoException;

    void Scapegoat()
    {
        if (state != "Correct State")
            throw new Exception("You called me at the wrong state!", moreInfoException);
    }

    void Culprit()
    {
        state = "Wrong State";
        moreInfoException = new Exception("Here's when YOU changed the state!");
    }
}
```

It prints this (note the missing trace from `Culprit` exception):

```
System.Exception: You called me at the wrong state! ---> System.Exception: Here's when YOU changed the state!
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MyApp.Thready.Scapegoat() in C:\src\MyApp\Program.cs:line 142
   at MyApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\src\MyApp\Program.cs:line 20
```

Here's one solution:

```
public class Thready
{
    string state;
    private ExceptionDispatchInfo captured;

    public void Scapegoat()
    {
        if (state != "Correct State")
        {
            try
            {
                captured.Throw();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("You called me at the wrong state!", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Culprit()
    {
        state = "Wrong State";
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Here's when YOU changed the state!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            captured = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints the correct trace:

```
System.Exception: You called me at the wrong state! ---> System.Exception: Here's when YOU changed the state!
   at MyApp.Thready.Culprit() in C:\src\MyApp\Program.cs:line 57
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MyApp.Thready.Scapegoat() in C:\src\MyApp\Program.cs:line 43
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MyApp.Thready.Scapegoat() in C:\src\MyApp\Program.cs:line 47
   at MyApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\src\MyApp\Program.cs:line 22
```

However that requires that I throw the exception, catch it and call the `Capture()` method in the `Culprit`. And then in `Scapegoat` I have to call `Throw()`, catch again, and wrap in the final exception. This looks slow.

Is there a faster and less bureaucratic/verbose solution?

Comment: what do you expect to see?

Comment: @vasily.sib edited to add the expected trace.

Comment: I see now. As far as I know, stacktrace is added to Exception object only when you throw it, so your solution is a direct one. Another option is to handle [StackTrace class directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.7.2), but you better do not overuse it heavily.